# can md-optgroup be selected

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, optgroup

I am looking for solution to select md-optgroup and md-option. I could not get any solution. Please help me on if any one has worked on this issue.

```
<md-select ng-model="selection" placeholder="Select an Option">
      <md-optgroup label="{{currentGroup}}" ng-repeat="currentGroup in groupList">
        <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {group: currentGroup}">{{item.name}}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/hrSzsq9H2uYw6HWVLWU9?p=preview

[image]